# How to negate a gitignore pattern containing spaces?

Tags: git

[My .gitignore](https://gitlab.com/victor-engmark/tilde/blob/master/.config/.gitignore) starts by excluding everything, and then negating everything that I want to include, to avoid lots of noise in `git status`:

```
*
!awesome/
!calibre/
[…]
```

However, after installing Visual Studio Code I can't seem to negate the match for the directory "Code - OSS". I've tried the following lines:

```
!Code - OSS/
!Code\ -\ OSS/
!'Code - OSS/'
!"Code - OSS/"
!Code*
```

With all of those lines at the bottom of my .gitignore `git status` still doesn't list this directory as available for inclusion.

---

The output of `git check-ignore --verbose Code\ -\ OSS` with each of those lines is also strange:

```
.config/.gitignore:22:!Code - OSS/  Code - OSS
.config/.gitignore:22:!Code\ -\ OSS/    Code - OSS
.config/.gitignore:1:*  Code - OSS
.config/.gitignore:1:*  Code - OSS
.config/.gitignore:22:!Code*    Code - OSS
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is a bug. Test case:

```
$ cd "$(mktemp --directory)"
$ mkdir foo\ bar
$ touch foo\ bar/test
$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /tmp/tmp.iGmBR6y2xR/.git/
$ git status --short 
?? foo bar/
$ cat > .gitignore << EOF
> *
> !foo bar
> !foo\ bar
> !"foo bar"
> "!foo bar"
> !foo bar/
> !foo\ bar/
> !"foo bar/"
> "!foo bar/"
> EOF
$ git status --short 
[no output]
```

Workaround/counter-test-case:

```
$ cat > .gitignore << EOF
> */
> !foo\ bar/
> EOF
$ git status --short 
?? .gitignore
?? foo bar/
```